# Suspected order of functions/while loop glitches game out

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

I INTEND MY CODE TO...

- Ask username and store username
- Show a menu screen, where player has to - Enter any key to start the game.
- Generation of number and reset "tries" when player inputs 'any prompt
- In game:
- Player bets and guesses.
- If wrong, back to the guess and bet. The variables balance and tries subtracts both the bet and -1 try.
- If guess is same as generated number, win screen. The player gets the variable prize added to his balance.
- Both win/loss displays the "choice" menu, and player is prompted to play again by replying yes or no.
- If yes, balance is updated with the prize/loss, new number is generated and balance is updated. Tries is also reset.
- If no, player gets sent back to menu.
- If tries == 0, then the "yes/no" choice prompt will apear again because the player lost, and the balance is updated with the loss.

THE PROBLEM IS...

- I suspect the order of the functions, and/or loop to restart/end the game, to be out of order.
- Everything works besides 1 thing: Entering yes/no when the game either won, or lost by reaching 0 tries, this happens:

PIC: 0[image]

I've tried changing the game_state variables, changing the if/elif statements and even tried to add more functions/while loops but nothing works for me.

I'm new to python and have reached the end of my rope.

MY CODE:

```
#pylint:disable=W0613
#pylint:disable=W0312
#pylint:disable=W0611
from random import randint
import math
######### NUMBER GUESSING GAME ##########

START_BALANCE = 500

POSITIVES = ["yes", "yeah", "y", "yep", "roger", "yea", "positive", "play"]
NEGATIVES = ["no", "nope", "n", "nah", "negative"]

choice = ("\nPlay again? Y/N:     ").upper()
userName = input ("Welcome to NumGuess! What is your name?\n")
userName = userName.title()

def menu():
    print(''' \n                        Hello {}!\n
                * The rules are very simple *
--         The AI generates a number from 1 - 100.       --
--    You will have to make a bet and enter your guess.  --
--   You have 10x tries. If you fail, you lose your bet. --
--   The AI will let say if you guessed 'low' or 'high'  --
--    Correct guess = prize. Wrong guess = lost bet.     --

                       - Good Luck! - 
'''.format(userName))

def menuPlay():

    try:
        menuPlay = input("Press any key to start the game.")
#   except (ValueError):
    #   return menuPlay()
    except TypeError:
        return menuPlay()
    else:
        if menuPlay.upper() != "":
            return

def xNumbers():
    number = randint(1,100)
    return number

def xTries():
    tries = 3
    return tries

def xBets():
    print("-------------------------------------")
    bet = int(input("Enter your bet:     "))
    return bet

def xGuesses():
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess:    "))
    return guess


menu()
menuPlay()
tries = xTries() 
number = xNumbers()

def main(tries, balance):
    print("\nYour balance is: {}$.\nYou have {}x tries left.\n".format(balance, tries))
    bet = xBets()
    guess = xGuesses()

    print("\nnumber: {}, guess: {}, bet: {}".format(number, guess, bet)) ##just to check if things are working

    if tries <=1:
        print("\nGAME OVER! - YOU ARE OUT OF TRIES!\n - The number was: {}.".format(number))
        input(choice)
        return [balance]

    if guess == number:
        prize = bet * float(3.75)
        prize = math.ceil(prize)
        balance += prize
        print("Congratulations! You win: {}$".format(prize))
        print("Your new balance is: {}$\n".format(balance))

    elif guess < number:
        print("Wrong guess!")
        print("- Your guess is too low!")
        tries -= 1
        balance -= bet
        main(tries, balance)
    elif guess > number:
        print("Wrong guess!")
        print("- Your guess is too high!")
        tries -= 1
        balance -= bet
        main(tries, balance)    

    player_Choice = input(choice)

    if player_Choice in POSITIVES: #If player wants to play again.
        print("New round started!")
        return [True, balance] #return True & updated balancd to while loop.

    else: # If player inputs NO to play again.
        print("\nThanks for playing!\n")
        return [False, balance] #return False & updated balnce to while loop - should end the game.
        # BONUS: If this could return to menuPlay() with an updated balance, that would be ideal.


game_state = [True, START_BALANCE]

while game_state[0]:
    game_state = main(tries, game_state[1])
```

`

Thank you for helping out a newbie!

Comment: You didn't actually include code, or a picture.

Comment: Corrected, sorry about that. I'm not sure what happened

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `if choice in POSITIVES`. Your `choice` variable is always pointing to `"\nPlay again? Y/N:     "` string, and choice player provides is never actually "recorded".

To fix this, you should

1. Save player answer, when you're calling `input(choice)` — i.e., `player_choice = input(choice)`.
2. Check against this variable, i.e. `if player_choice in POSITIVES`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in these calls:

```
input(choice)
```

It should be

```
choice = input("\nPlay again? Y/N:     ")
```

Your code is using the variable `choice` to mean both the prompt and the user's response to the prompt (`if choice in POSITIVES:`).